# Is there any problem in NBA 2k16 's graphics?

Tags: nba2k16

I have been trying hard to lower the settings as much as I can, but still my copy of NBA 2K16 (PC version) is full of lags. My specs:

Intel Core I5 5200u 2.2Ghz
8 GB RAM
Nvidia Geforce 940m 2 GB

I have confirmed my settings on sites like Game Debate, but still NBA is lagging.

Is there any problem in the game or the specs are not good enough?

Answer (score -2):

I5 5200U this cpu is not very powerful. There is a name rule for Intel mobile cpus'.

for example:
i5 5200 U
i5 5200 H
i5 5200 QM

Cpu's with "U" save more power and have lower heat in processing.
H and QM are more powerful and have a standard power consumption and heat generation.

You can also change the screen resolution to make the game run in a low Screen Resolution.